# Theorems on Modular Arithmetic

Tags: number-theory

Let $$a^x \equiv b^x \pmod p$$ and $$a^y \equiv b^y \pmod p$$ and $\gcd(y, x)=1$ then prove that $$a \equiv b \pmod p$$
As it is given that gcd$(y, x)=1$ so by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic there exists integers $u$ and $v$ such that $ux+vy=1$. Now without the loss of generality let us assume that $a < b$ then $b=a+k$ for some positive integer $k$. Now $$a+k=(a+k)^{ux+vy} \equiv a^{ux+vy}=a \pmod p.$$ So we get $p$ divides $k=b-a$. So $b \equiv a \pmod p$

$$$$$ Is My Proof Correct???

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean $a\equiv b\bmod p$ where you wrote $x\equiv y\bmod p$ ?

Comment: Formatting tip:  `$\bmod p$` produces $\bmod p$

Comment: Yes I mean $a \equiv b \bmod p$

Comment: Is the proof correct?

Comment: You need to explain on $(a+k)^{ux+vy} \equiv a^{ux+vy}$, otherwise you are assuming what you are to prove. But I see no other problem

Comment: And for that. $(a+k)^{ux+vy} \equiv b^{ux+vy} \equiv (b^x)^u (b^y)^v \equiv (a^x)^u (a^y)^v  \equiv a^{ux+vy}$

Comment: Introducing the $k$ serves no apparent purpose.  You could just as easily have written $b\equiv b^{ux+vy}\equiv a^{ux+vy}\equiv a \pmod p$.

Comment: @lulu I agree with that. nice observation

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain on $(a+k)^{ux+vy} \equiv a^{ux+vy}$, otherwise you are assuming what you are to prove. But I see no other problem .

And for that. $(a+k)^{ux+vy} \equiv b^{ux+vy} \equiv (b^x)^u (b^y)^v \equiv (a^x)^u (a^y)^v  \equiv a^{ux+vy}$

Edit:
as @lulu said $k$ is not serving any purpose.

Comment: But $u$ and $v$ both are not positive integers then how can we write $(b^x)^u(b^y)^v \equiv (a^x)^u(a^y)^v$

Comment: $a^u$ has integer solution, even when $u<0$ for modular arithmetic. $3^{-1} \equiv 5$ when working with modulo $7$.

Comment: If that answered your question please mark it as solution.